# ¿Cuál es la forma de asignarle un valor a una variable, cuando una consulta a Mysql no optiene resultado?

Tags: mysql

Necesito comprobar que en una tabla, que contiene un campo "estado", todos los registros de este campo son iguales a "atendido" y, si se cumple esta condición, obtener un resultado con el cual pueda realizar otras acciones, el problema que es que no logro definir el tipo de valor que obtengo cuando una consulta no obtiene resultado, quisiera poder definir que tipo de valor es, para lograr comprobarlo dentro de una variable.

El lenguaje utilizado es PHP, por tanto:

¿Cómo dar un valor a una variable, cuando una consulta "Select" a Mysql no obtiene resultado?

Comment: Hola, y disculpa es mi primera pregunta, me esforzaré por hacerlo mejor

Comment: Hola Rosy Bienvenida a Stackoverflow ¿Qué lenguaje de programación estas usando?

Comment: Estoy utilizando "php" , Ivandez, y gracias de antemano...

Comment: Es probable que ya podamos responder a tu pregunta pero, para estar seguros, es mejor que compartas el código PHP del momento en el que ejecutas la consulta y a qué variable te refieres.

Comment: $sql=$conexion->query ("SELECT * FROM solicitud_servicio WHERE id_venta = $v_id and estado IN('En Espera', 'Generada', 'Cancelada') ");
   
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())
    
     {    
      
     
     if (is_null($row['estado']; ))
      
      {
       echo " es nula"; 
      }
     else
      {
       echo " no es nula"; 
      }
     
     } ;

Comment: //  Intento comprobar que todos los registros del campo "Estado" sean iguales a "Atendida" o que no existan estos otros tipos de estado "En Espera, Generada, Cancelada"; Si estos estados diferentes a "Atendida" no existe, obviamente la consulta no tendrá resultado; y al comprobar este resultado que suponemos "null" y que se almacena en la VAR $row , ejecutar otras acciones...

Answer (score 0):

Cuando una consulta no retorna resultados puedes hacer uso de `$num_rows`.

```
$result = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM ...");

$rowsReturned = $result->num_rows;

// Si no retorna resultados, asignas el valor a tu variable.
if(empty($rowsReturned)){
    $someVariable = ...
}
```

Puedes revisar acerca de esto en la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

Comment: Jonatan como ejemplo tome el código que me muestras y cambie el mío a esto: <code> $sql=$conexion->query ("SELECT * FROM solicitud_servicio WHERE id_venta = $v_id and estado IN('En Espera', 'Generada', 'Cancelada') ");
$rowsReturned = $sql->num_rows; 
 
     if(empty($rowsReturned))
     
      {
          echo "es null";
      }
      
     else 
      {
      echo "no es null";
      
      }  </code>

Comment: ¿Lograste hacer lo que buscabas con esa respuesta?

Comment: Logre hacerlo estimado Jonatan, te agradezco, hazme un favor mas, como o cual es la forma de enviar el código consultado en comentarios para que  se muestre ordenado ? no tengo opciones para hacerlo, como activo el menú para formato de comentarios ?

Comment: me refiero a la forma de ingresar <código> al momento de realizar un comentario en este foro, de tal manera que el código se muestre ordenado y sombreado al igual que el que me mostraste, a diferencia el mío se ve como un simple texto... No tengo opciones para dar formato al texto que ingreso en los comentarios del foro (preguntas ,respuestas)

Comment: En un comentario no es posible mostrar ordenado el código, simplemente puedes sombrearlo, colocando el código entre backticks `(\`)`.  Por ejemplo `<code>`.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer la [página de ayuda](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) para hacer uso de esos elementos de marcado. En especial el apartado de `comment formatting`

Comment: gracias por la ayuda jontan y bendiciones